# how can I resolve in a base state and get that resolved value when using named views?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

TLDR: I can't get the resolve function in the base state to work *and* get my named views to display the right thing.

I've got a set of working routes with named views ([docs here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)) that look like this:

```
    $stateProvider.state("index",
      url: ""
      views:
        viewA:
          templateUrl: "/partials/index.A.jade"
          controller: ($scope) ->
            console.log('index controller') # just confirming that I'm hitting this line
        viewB:
          templateUrl: "/partials/index.B.jade"
    )
    ... etc, 5+ states
```

I need to add in a resolve to load lodash via a promise:

```
  resolve: util: ($q, $window) ->
    console.log 'resolving base state'
    deferred = $q.defer()
    require(["cdn-lodash"], (lodash) ->
      util = lib: lodash, logger: $window.logger
      deferred.resolve(util)
    )
    deferred.promise
```

If I attach this resolve to the index state it works fine. But I need lodash in many states so I'd rather just load it for all states (alternately I could call this base "util" and add it in as a base for the states that need it:

```
$stateProvider.state('base',
  abstract: true
  resolve: util: ($q, $window) ->
    console.log 'resolving base state'
    deferred = $q.defer()
    require(["cdn-lodash"], (lodash) ->
      util = lib: lodash, logger: $window.logger
      deferred.resolve(util)
    )
    deferred.promise
)

$stateProvider.state("base.index",
  url: ""
  views:
    viewA:
      templateUrl: "/partials/index.A.jade"
      controller: ($scope, util) ->
        debugger
        console.log('index controller')
        console.log util
        $scope.allowAdmin = true
    viewB:
      templateUrl: "/partials/index.B.jade"
```

Well that doesn't work because none of my named views are loading, I just get a blank page. The resolve is being hit though. The page loads fine with no errors and the page headers etc in layout.jade are loading. So I tried adding the A/B views to the `base` state:

```
  views:
    viewA: templateUrl: ''
    viewB: templateUrl: ''
```

Crud, now the views are loading, but not correctly. The A view is in the markup twice while the B view (which is empty on the index page) is not there at all. In the short term I think I can fix this by making a resolve function outside of the state declaration and putting it in the resolve for each state.

Also one other complication: most of my controllers are declared in their own files so the views line looks like:

```
  views:
    viewA:
      controller: 'adminUserList' # <<<<<<<--------- this line
      templateUrl: "/partials/admin/user/list.A.jade"
    viewB:
      templateUrl: "/partials/admin/user/list.B.jade")
```

Comment: Could you possibly post the entire code listing to a plunkr or something? It's probably a really simple issue, but it'd be much easier to debug if I could see how your templates and states were interacting.